# Cannot finding my unpublished Alexa Skills Kit

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

A custom Skill has been created without being published.

[image]

I am able to test it in **Service Simulator**.

When I try to add the skills to my device from the web portal (http://alexa.amazon.com/) or the Alexa app on my phone, the search get no result.

I have made sure the Alexa device (my raspberry pi) is using the same developer account. What step have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug, amazon is currently working on it. because of which you are unable to find your skill. The same thing happened to me.
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/articles/30222/0628-issue-with-development-skills-not-showing-up.html

Comment: Link seems to be dead

Answer (score 3):

Check the "test" tab and make sure the skill is "Enabled".

Answer (score 2):

If some people still have the same issue after filling the Publishing tab, I just struggled with it for a day and I think I found a workaround. 
I ended up adding my second e-mail address as beta-tester, and I was able to enable my skill and now I see it in "Your skills"

Hope this can help :)

Answer (score 0):

**One problem related to Language settings.**

Correct the language settings in your Echo Device using https://alexa.amazon.in/ or alexa app. Make sure language enabled in skill and device are equal. For example, use English India.

Go to https://alexa.amazon.in/.
Make sure device appears online.
Disable the skill in Your Skill section.
Enable it again.

This should solve the problem.